# LWJGL Thin Matrix tutorials GUI

Tags: gui, lwjgl

I have a question about the GUI implemented by Thinmatrix. For positions we have to use values between [-1, 1]. This is probably because the origin of the screen is the center and then we have a 1 by 1 grid.
Is there a possibility to change this up, and reposition the origin to for example the top left corner, and make the screen a lot bigger to use absolute coordinates instead of values between [-1, 1]

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute coordinates"? Do you mean pixel coordinates? In that case you just have to do some math: `actual_pos = (pixel_pos / screen_pixel_width) * 2 - 1`. As for changing the origin to the top left corner you just have to subtract 1 from both x and y when you calculate the position (so if 0, 0 is top left you sub 1 and you get -1, -1 which is the correct top left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates are in normalized device coordinate range, because no further transformation is applied.

You can set up an orthographic projection matrix with appropriate values to get the desired behavior.
I would suggest using a math library, contrary to what he does in the tutorials, because you really don't need to write everything yourself. [JOML](https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML-CI) is a good one for this.

In your shader, just multiply your `gl_Position` by it. That's it.